# UIActivityViewControllerのシェア機能でFacebookだけ中身が空っぽになる

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

ユーザーがアプリ上で作成した情報を、UIActivityViewControllerを使って、メール・Twitter・Facebookなど様々な方法でシェアさせる機能を開発しています。

下記のようなコードを実装したのですが、Facebookでの投稿シェア時に、本文が空っぽになってしまいます。

いろいろ試行錯誤してみたのですが、問題の原因がわからず、解決の緒になるヒントなどを頂けたら幸いです。よろしくお願い致します。

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://apple.co/1bvqKT4"];
NSString *text = @"test";
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hoge.png"];
UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:@[text,url,image]applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

添付画像１枚目：Facebookでシェアした時のスクリーンショット。画像だけはシェアされるものの、本文とURLがシェアされない

添付画像２枚目：メールでシェアした時のスクリーンショット。すべてちゃんとシェアされている。

添付画像３枚目：Facebookでシェアした後のタイムライン

[image: メールでシェアした場合はちゃんと内容が表示される]
[image: Facebookでシェアした場合、空っぽになる]
[image: Facebookでシェアした後のタイムライン]

Comment: コード中に `![画像の説明をここに入力][1]` と書かれていますが、これ実際のコードにはないですよね？

Comment: あ、申し訳ありません。間違いです。修正いたしました。
ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Comment: Facebookで投稿前の画像ですが、このまま、実際に投稿しても本文・URLは添付されないままでしょうか？

Comment: はい、画像以外は表示されません。参考までに私のタイムラインのスクリーンショットを追加しました。

Comment: こちらでも少し実験してみましたが、画像が入ってると画像のみになるようですね。画像なしでテキストとURLを投稿すると、そっちが正常に投稿されました。こういう仕様なのかどうかは謎ですが。

Comment: わざわざ実験までしていただき、ありがとうございます。画像よりもテキストとURLのほうが大事なので、その２つだけでいいやと思い、私も実験してみたのですが、やはりテキストは空っぽのままでした。コードは下記の部分を書き換えました。もしよろしければ、どのようにコードを書くべきかアドバイスいただけませんか。  
  
[修正前]  
UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:@[text,url,image]applicationActivities:nil];  
  
[修正後]  
UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:@[text,url]applicationActivities:nil];

Comment: その修正で特に問題ないように思われます。ちなみに、こちらで実験して気がついた注意点ですが、画像の無い投稿をFacebookでシェアする場合、iOSの[設定] - [Facebook]から使用するアカウントでログインしている必要があるようです。

Comment: はい、iOSの設定で使用するアカウントでログインしているのですが、空っぽです、、、

Comment: こちらで調べた結果を回答にまとめておきました・・・　が、そちらの問題の解決にはなってないようです。あとは、自力でがんばってください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

簡単に実験してみましたが、なかなか、不思議な動作をしているようです。

- テキスト／URL／画像データをセットで投稿した場合 → 画像データだけが投稿される
- テキスト／URLを投稿した場合 → テキスト／URLが投稿される

実験に使ったコードはこんな感じです。
（iOS 8.3／Xcode 6.3.1／iPhone 5Sで確認）

```
/// テキスト／URL／画像データを投稿
@IBAction func onShareAll(sender: AnyObject) {
    let text = "Text + URL + Image"
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://apple.co/1bvqKT4")
    let image = UIImage(named: "pic1")

    // なぜか、画像だけが投稿される
    let items = [text, url!, image!]

    let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)
    presentViewController(activity, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

/// テキスト／URLを投稿
@IBAction func onShareText(sender: AnyObject) {
    let text = "Text + URL"
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://apple.co/1bvqKT4")

    // テキストとURLが正常に投稿される
    let items = [text, url!]

    let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)
    presentViewController(activity, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

- 画像を含む投稿の結果  
  [image: 画像を含む投稿の結果]
- テキスト／URLの投稿の結果  
  [image: テキスト／URLの投稿の結果]

ちなみに、Facebookのアプリだけログインしていた場合、画像の投稿は出来るけどテキスト／URLの投稿は上手く行きませんでした。こちらは、iOSの[設定] - [Facebook]からログインしておくことで、テキスト／URLの投稿に成功しました。

Comment: こんなに丁寧にテストしていただき、ありがとうございます。しばらく探していたら本家stackoverflowのほうにこういうPostをみつけました。どうやらFBアプリの仕様変更によるもののようです。

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879354/facebook-is-not-shown-in-uiactivityviewcontroller-but-twitter-does

しかし、See.Kuさんのところではtext & urlのシェアができたということで、これは新発見かもしれませんね！唯一の違いは swiftか、obj-Cかという点しかないので、swiftだとなぜか動く、ということなのですかね・・・。

致し方ないのでは、私はこの方法はあきらめて、FBでのシェアだけ、別のボタンを作って、FB SDKを使ったシェアを検討したいと思います。

このたびはどうもありがとうございました。